# Insured car destroyed, insurance company not picking up the phone

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

My insured car was destroyed by an online player but when I call the insurance company  they do not answer. When I call my mechanic, the car is there but in brackets it says (destroyed).

Is there any possible way for me to get it back?

Comment: Try calling any other "game time". It happened to me, and I just had to call like 3 times.

Comment: what do you be exactly by calling any other "game time"?

Comment: ive been calling for a while an nothing happens :/.... imma try again tho

Comment: I mean in different hours. When it happened to me, I just do a matchmaking and when I exited to the free mode, it was 10 am, I called and it worked.

Comment: ever get this fixed? This is also happening to me

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing 6/10 of my cars are destroyed but no mors mutual is working. I've tried over 1000 times and they aren't cheap cars to replace

Comment: I think it's an attempt by rockstar to inject some realism into the game.

Comment: I was thinking realism too; I actually had a friend have this problem in a free roam instance where i had just blown up a bunch of cars and i was wondering if they actually took into account the call volume from random npcs because of that. In any case it cleared up after a short while.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a known bug.

> There's a bug that makes insured cars become uninsured, then when your car is destroyed you can't claim it back because it doesn't have insurance

Found this here:
[Rockstar Support Community](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200679586-Warning-about-car-loss)

So there is no solution but you could try to send Rockstar a ticket so they bother more about that bug.

Comment: I'm not sure, but wouldn't uninsured cars be removed from your garage instead of being listed as destroyed like the OP mentioned?